# What is the difference between ldobj and ldind.<type>, and why is ldobj faster?

Tags: c#, clr, bytecode, il

When using a 64-bit sized struct, the following code snippet

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 8)]
  unsafe struct BUF
  {
  }

((BUF*)dst) = *((BUF*)src);
```

Produces

```
    IL_0046: nop          
    IL_0047: ldloc.s dst                              
    IL_0049: ldloc.2                                       
    IL_004a: ldobj MyClass/BUF           
    IL_004f: stobj MyClass/BUF
```

However, when just using a long, the following code produces

```
*((long*)dst) = *((long*)src);
```

Produces:

```
IL_0046: nop
IL_0047: ldloc.s dst
IL_0049: ldloc.2
IL_004a: ldind.i8                       
IL_004b: stind.i8
```

Does anyone know what difference ldobj/stobj and ldind.i8/stind.i8 makes, if any, for this example?

ldobj/stobj seems to give a 20% performance improvement, but I cannot figure out why that is happening. Aren't these two lines doing the exact same thing?

Thanks!

edit: [64-bit release mode] The bytecode looks the same when compiled in release mode. The performance measurement was done a while ago in release mode.

Comment: Please specify if the was tested under 32-bit or 64-bit mode and the version of the CLR.

Comment: Did you test in Release mode *without* debugger attached?

Comment: This was tested in debug mode. I will check again in release mode now.

Comment: I would take a look at the JIT compiled code to see the difference.

Comment: How can I look at the JIT compiled code? I am currently using ILSpy to view the bytecode.

Comment: You can look at the compiled code using WinDbg/SOS. Once the method has been compiled, you can dump the platform specific code using the `!u` command. You can find the address of the method using the `!dumpmt` command.

Comment: But before you do that, you really need to test in release mode. Debug builds are not optimized, so whatever perf numbers you get are not that interesting.

Comment: Brian is absolutely right. Testing for performance in debug mode tells you *nothing*. And even testing a release-compiled assembly while debugging it tells you nothing. The jitter turns off optimizations in those cases to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, the performance measurement was run in release mode. My initial post included bytecode (as seen with ILSpy) in debug mode, and I've confirmed the bytecode is the same (in ILSpy at least) when compiled in release mode.

I'm will download WinDbg/SOS to check again.

Comment: You can use VS to see the assembly code. Just click "Go to disassembly" in the context menu. Make sure to attach the debugger *after* the process has started (and please confirm that you actually did this). The IL code does not matter - the JIT'ed x86 is important.

Comment: Just to confirm, will WindDbg show me different bytecode than what I see in ILSpy/IL DASM? Both variations look exactly the same (as what I posted above) in IL DASM as well.

usr: I've never tried attaching the debugger. I'll try that now. Thanks!

Comment: WinDbg does not show bytecode (or does it?). It should show x86.

Comment: SOS can show both, `!u` shows platform code. `!dumpil` shows IL. However, just go with VS. It will be easier. WinDbg/SOS is my hammer, so I use it for everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've replicated the two distinct methods you're using, and see the same IL being generated, however the jitted code for the two is absolutely identical when run in Release mode:

Here's the test method I used:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 8)]
    unsafe struct BUF
    {
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            BUF x, y, z;
            unsafe
            {
                Do1(&x, &y);
                Do2(&y, &z);
            }
            // Readline here to allow attaching debugger and dumping jitted code
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // Disable inlining to permit easier identification of the code
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        unsafe static void Do1(BUF* src, BUF* dst)
        {
            *((BUF*)dst) = *((BUF*)src);
        }

        // Disable inlining to permit easier identification of the code
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        unsafe static void Do2(BUF* src, BUF* dst)
        {
            *((long*)dst) = *((long*)src);
        }
    }
}
```

The IL for the two methods match yours:

`Do1`:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.1 
IL_0001: ldarg.0 
IL_0002: ldobj Test.BUF
IL_0007: stobj Test.BUF
IL_000c: ret
```

`Do2`:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.1 
IL_0001: ldarg.0 
IL_0002: ldind.i8 
IL_0003: stind.i8 
IL_0004: ret
```

And dumping the jitted code:

`Do1`:

```
Test.Program.Do1(Test.BUF*, Test.BUF*)
Begin 000007ff00170190, size 7
000007ff`00170190 488b01          mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx]
000007ff`00170193 488902          mov     qword ptr [rdx],rax
000007ff`00170196 c3              ret
```

`Do2`:

```
Test.Program.Do2(Test.BUF*, Test.BUF*)
Begin 000007ff001701b0, size 7
000007ff`001701b0 488b01          mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx]
000007ff`001701b3 488902          mov     qword ptr [rdx],rax
000007ff`001701b6 c3              ret
```

They look pretty identical to me.

Comment: Thank you Iridium! This leads me to think that maybe I'm doing something stupid when measuring the performance... let me dig further.

Comment: How do you attach the debugger in release mode?

When I try to do so (after the program is started) I get a pop-up saying "The following module was built either with optimizations enables or without debug information ... change it to Debug mode."

Comment: @r3su I was using Windbg, not Visual Studio.

Comment: It seems to have been a problem with the way I was testing performance (being too granular with the Stopwatch). It would have dawned on me much faster if I thought to check the assembly code.

Thanks again Iridium!